# playframework load models from xml

Tags: xml, playframework, yaml

currently playframework offers possibility to load models into db from YAML files. but strangely i couldn't find an example of loading models from xml. can we load models from xml like we do with YAML? or is this `Fixtures.loadModels()` methods only available for YAML data files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play 1.2 only offers to load models from yaml. I am not sure about play 2.

Comment: i'm not yet using play 2 . i find verion 2 is a major release very different from version 1. so i'm scared to do the transition in a middle of my play project

Comment: I wouldn't recommend moving to play 2 in the middle of your project, except if personal or experimenting. If you need to load data from xml you might need to parser parse the file yourself in a bootstrap job and save the data.

Comment: yes i did an xml parsing in the job bootstrap. however i encountered a problem when using 'db=fs' i got an error saying that a filed value is too large to be stored. when i set 'db=mem' this error was fixed. do you know what could be the problem of 'db=fs' ? why doesn't it work with large text content eventhough i use the `@Lob` annotation to mark the large string i want to store in db?

Comment: This sound like a limitation of the embedded database. I seem to remember (might be wrong) that it does not support lob. Can you test it against a 'real' database (i.e. mysql)?

Comment: yes i'll setup a Mysql db and use it in my app. i just though the embedded db 'db=fs' could be used for storing Lob content ; but it seems it doesn't for 'fs' . however it works for 'db=mem' which seems wiered.